# Why the value of same variable in heap of object 1 not reflected in object2?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

```
s(const s& src)
{ 
    cout<<"Copy\n";
    p =src.p;
}

void disp(int x=0)
{  
    *p = x;
    cout <<"Value at p :"<<*p <<endl<< p<<endl;
}

};// relevant piece of code


s s1;
s s2 = s1;    
s1.disp(200);
s2.disp();
```

In this program what i was expecting was since the data member p of objects s1 and s2
 point to the same memory location any change in the value of p of object s1 should 
reflect the value of p in object s2.In the output its clear that address holded by p
is same for both s1 and s2.but i didnt get the expected result 200 for s2.disp
function.Output is

```
Copy
Value at p :200
0x1e069010
Value at p :0
0x1e069010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify `p` in `disp` - `*p = x;`. When you call `s2.disp();` the default `0` is used. (`void disp(int x=0)`), so you set `*p` to `0`.

Comment: >My intension was  to display that any change in the value of p because of s1 will reflect the value of p in s2 also.Could you pls make a bit change in the above program to get the output like that.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was right,just make the variable p as public and print *(s2.p) right after calling s1.disp();.I can see the value of p for s2 displaying as  200

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you modify `p` in the method `dist` :

*p = x;

In the second case, when you call `s2.disp()` the default value `0` is used, and `*p` has the value `0`.

To reflect what you want, you can do :

```
class s
{
public:
    s(const s& src)
    { 
        cout<<"Copy\n";
        p = src.p;
    }

    void Display() const    // Display method just display
    {
        cout << "Value at p :" << *p << endl << p << endl;
    }

    void UpdateP( int x = 0 )
    {
        *p = x;
    }
};

s s1;
s s2 = s1;    
s1.UpdateP(200);
s1.Display();
s2.Display();
```

Just a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/N5vYFF), the code is not the prettiest but it shows you that it is working.

Comment: >Thanks a lot for this nice example.